# Prove that $f(x) = \frac{\sin(x+\alpha)}{\sin(x+\beta)}$ is monotonic in any interval of its domain

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, proof-writing

> Prove that $f(x) = \frac{\sin(x+\alpha)}{\sin(x+\beta)}$ is monotonic in any interval of its domain, where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb R$

Obviously $x + \beta \ne \pi n$. Then i've tried to split the problem into three parts: $\alpha = \beta$, $\alpha > \beta$, $\beta > \alpha$.

For the first case it's obvious that the function turns into a constant and therefore is monotonic.

Since $f(x)$ is periodic we may use that fact and consider some interval for example $(0, {\pi\over2})$ or $(0, \pi)$. But since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ may take any values i didn't manage to figure out any inequality to start from.

What steps should i take to proceed?

Comment: Take a derivative and hope its sign never changes?

Comment: The "in any interval of its domain" part is important. You might want to add it to the title (which is false as it stands).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using $$
 \sin((x+\beta) + (\alpha - \beta)) = \sin(x+\beta) \cos (\alpha - \beta) + \cos(x+\beta) \sin (\alpha - \beta)
$$
one gets
$$
f(x) =  \cos (\alpha - \beta) + \cot(x+\beta) \sin (\alpha - \beta)
$$
and the cotangent is decreasing on each interval of its domain.

You could also attack the problem by substituting $x + \alpha = y$
first, then the expression becomes
$$
  \frac{\sin(y + \alpha - \beta)}{\sin(y)}
$$
Now substitute $\gamma = \alpha - \beta$, and you are left with
$$
 g(y) = \frac{\sin(y + \gamma)}{\sin(y)}
$$
which might be easier to handle.

Comment: It should be $\cot$, not $\tan$, right?

Comment: @MPW: Oops, yes...

Comment: Nice, +1 ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I have to admire this approach, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Differentiating with respect to $x$ we get
$$f'(x)=\sin (\alpha -\beta ) \left(-\csc ^2(\beta +x)\right)$$

Comment: +1, not sure why someone downvoted, excellent hint

Comment: Maybe because the tags seem to indicate that solutions involving calculus are not acceptable? Just guessing.